# Two bootstrap popovers on the same page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have two popovers on the same page, one triggered on click, another on hover, and when I open first one, and go to the second (on hover) this closes my first popover. Then when I go back to the first one I need two clicks to open popover. What I supposed to do?

Comment: could you post a jsfiddle or jsbin of your code?

Comment: Can you post your code please?